# Astropy: iterating over columns in table with a certain pattern in column name

Tags: max, astropy

I have an astropy table `t` such that `t.colnames` shows something like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'err_a', 'err_b', 'err_c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I would like to determine for each row in the table the maximal value for the columns that have `'err'` in the name.

I can do something like

```
for line in t:
    max = 0
    for col in t.colnames:
        if col[:3] == 'err':
            if line[col] > max:
                max = line[col]
    print(max)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: When you write "for each row" do you want the max per-row, or the max across all rows (which is what your code seems to be doing)?

Comment: I want the max per-row. I fixed the snippet. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the max value across all the "err" columns, you could do this:

```
max(t[c].max() for c in t.colnames if 'err' in c)
```

For the max per-row it's slightly trickier since the data in Astropy tables is typically column-oriented. It's probably simplest to convert the relevant columns to a Numpy array and broadcast the max function along the row axis; this is slightly trickier because you need to convert the array from a mixed-type to single type (assuming all the "err" columns are the same dtype, say, float64):

```
err_cols = [c for c in t.colnames if 'err' in c]
t.as_array(names=err_cols).view(dtype=float).reshape((len(t), len(err_cols))).max(axis=1)
```